# How to set Perforce client to english messages?

Tags: perforce

Whenever I get error from perforce server it's printed as question marks.
I want to resolve this by setting client to english language without charset (default locale).

But even if I delete utf8-bom from WorkspaceSettings.xml it gets repopulated after quitting P4V visual client. After opening command line in P4V it shows P4CHARSET=utf8-bom. I don't have environment variables so I don't know where it gets utf8-bom value. It would be ok but this charset does not work for me.

Is this possible to revert behavior to default english locale?

Perforce Server version: P4D/NTX64/2012.1/473528 (2012/05/31)
P4V 2015.1/1233444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a problem with OS messages, not perforce messages. OS produces localized error message, perforce server encodes it incorrectly. I suppose this can be solved by setting perforce server to UTF8.

But we use a workaround:
P4V client version June 2011 somehow works correctly with server in this situation.